# How to import Image alt, titles or File description?

Tags: feeds

Hello Drupal Community,

In a Product display i have image and file fields, I was wondering if there is a bulk way to import image alt text and image title or File description?

I used feeds to import images and multiple Files into product display but i cant find a mapping options to link alt, title or file description.
Also i was considering it is possible with VBO by executing arbitrary PHP script.

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thank you
Darius

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this issue is to use the [ImageField Tokens](https://drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens) module:

> The ImageField Tokens module extends the default functionality of
>   Image fields adding the ability to specify default values and use node
>   tokens in the Alt and Title text.

The module [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) is required. After you install and enable the modules, you configure its settings in the field properties for each individual content type.